# How to compare ROC AUC scores of different binary classifiers and assess statistical significance in Python? (p-value, confidence interval)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, statistics

I would like to compare different binary classifiers in Python. For that, I want to calculate the ROC AUC scores, measure the **95% confidence interval (CI)**, and ***p-value*** to access statistical significance.

Below is a minimal example in scikit-learn which trains three different models on a binary classification dataset, plots the ROC curves and calculates the AUC scores.

Here are my specific questions:

1. How to calculate the **95% confidence interval (CI)** of the ROC AUC scores on the test set? (e.g. with bootstrapping).
2. How to compare the AUC scores (on test set) and measure the ***p-value*** to assess statistical significance? (The null hypothesis is that the models are not different. Rejecting the null hypothesis means the difference in AUC scores is statistically significant.)

.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2018)

from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, roc_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = load_breast_cancer()

X = data.data
y = data.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=17)

# Naive Bayes Classifier
nb_clf = GaussianNB()
nb_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
nb_prediction_proba = nb_clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]

# Ranodm Forest Classifier
rf_clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20)
rf_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
rf_prediction_proba = rf_clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]

# Multi-layer Perceptron Classifier
mlp_clf = MLPClassifier(alpha=1, hidden_layer_sizes=150)
mlp_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
mlp_prediction_proba = mlp_clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]


def roc_curve_and_score(y_test, pred_proba):
    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), pred_proba.ravel())
    roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test.ravel(), pred_proba.ravel())
    return fpr, tpr, roc_auc


plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})
plt.grid()
fpr, tpr, roc_auc = roc_curve_and_score(y_test, rf_prediction_proba)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='darkorange', lw=2,
         label='ROC AUC={0:.3f}'.format(roc_auc))
fpr, tpr, roc_auc = roc_curve_and_score(y_test, nb_prediction_proba)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='green', lw=2,
         label='ROC AUC={0:.3f}'.format(roc_auc))
fpr, tpr, roc_auc = roc_curve_and_score(y_test, mlp_prediction_proba)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='crimson', lw=2,
         label='ROC AUC={0:.3f}'.format(roc_auc))
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=1, linestyle='--')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('1 - Specificity')
plt.ylabel('Sensitivity')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Bootstrap for 95% confidence interval

You want to repeat your analysis on multiple resamplings of your data. In the general case, assume you have a function `f(x)` that determines whatever statistic you need from data `x` and you can bootstrap like this:

```
def bootstrap(x, f, nsamples=1000):
    stats = [f(x[np.random.randint(x.shape[0], size=x.shape[0])]) for _ in range(nsamples)]
    return np.percentile(stats, (2.5, 97.5))
```

This gives you so-called plug-in estimates of the 95% confidence interval (i.e. you just take the percentiles of the bootstrap distribution).

In your case, you can write a more specific function like this

```
def bootstrap_auc(clf, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, nsamples=1000):
    auc_values = []
    for b in range(nsamples):
        idx = np.random.randint(X_train.shape[0], size=X_train.shape[0])
        clf.fit(X_train[idx], y_train[idx])
        pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
        roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test.ravel(), pred.ravel())
        auc_values.append(roc_auc)
    return np.percentile(auc_values, (2.5, 97.5))
```

Here, `clf` is the classifier for which you want to test the performance and `X_train`, `y_train`, `X_test`, `y_test` are like in your code.

This gives me the following confidence intervals (rounded to three digits, 1000 bootstrap samples):

- Naive Bayes: 0.986 [0.980 0.988]  (estimate, lower and upper limit of confidence interval)
- Random Forest: 0.983 [0.974 0.989]
- Multilayer Perceptron: 0.974 [0.223 0.98]

## Permutation tests to test against chance performance

A permutation test would technically go over all permutations of your observation sequence and evaluate your roc curve with the permuted target values (features are not permuted). This is ok if you have a few observations, but it becomes very costly if you more observations. It is therefore common to subsample the number of permutations and simply do a number of random permutations. Here, the implementation depends a bit more on the specific thing you want to test. The following function does that for your roc_auc values

```
def permutation_test(clf, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, nsamples=1000):
    idx1 = np.arange(X_train.shape[0])
    idx2 = np.arange(X_test.shape[0])
    auc_values = np.empty(nsamples)
    for b in range(nsamples):
        np.random.shuffle(idx1)  # Shuffles in-place
        np.random.shuffle(idx2)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train[idx1])
        pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
        roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test[idx2].ravel(), pred.ravel())
        auc_values[b] = roc_auc
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
    roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test.ravel(), pred.ravel())
    return roc_auc, np.mean(auc_values >= roc_auc)
```

This function again takes your classifier as `clf` and returns the AUC value on the unshuffled data and the p-value (i.e. probability to observe an AUC value larger than or equal to what you have in the unshuffled data).

Running this with 1000 samples gives p-values of 0 for all three classifiers. Note that these are not exact because of the sampling, but they are an indicating that all of these classifiers perform better than chance.

## Permutation test for differences between classifiers

This is much easier. Given two classifiers, you have prediction for every observation. You just shuffle the assignment between predictions and classifiers like this

```
def permutation_test_between_clfs(y_test, pred_proba_1, pred_proba_2, nsamples=1000):
    auc_differences = []
    auc1 = roc_auc_score(y_test.ravel(), pred_proba_1.ravel())
    auc2 = roc_auc_score(y_test.ravel(), pred_proba_2.ravel())
    observed_difference = auc1 - auc2
    for _ in range(nsamples):
        mask = np.random.randint(2, size=len(pred_proba_1.ravel()))
        p1 = np.where(mask, pred_proba_1.ravel(), pred_proba_2.ravel())
        p2 = np.where(mask, pred_proba_2.ravel(), pred_proba_1.ravel())
        auc1 = roc_auc_score(y_test.ravel(), p1)
        auc2 = roc_auc_score(y_test.ravel(), p2)
        auc_differences.append(auc1 - auc2)
    return observed_difference, np.mean(auc_differences >= observed_difference)
```

With this test and 1000 samples, I find no significant differences between the three classifiers:

- Naive bayes vs random forest: diff=0.0029, p(diff>)=0.311
- Naive bayes vs MLP: diff=0.0117, p(diff>)=0.186
- random forest vs MLP: diff=0.0088, p(diff>)=0.203

Where diff denotes the difference in roc curves between the two classifiers and p(diff>) is the empirical probability to observe a larger difference on a shuffled data set.

Comment: One question that arises: How to get the p-values, confidence intervals for large/complex models such as deep CNNs? Is there any workaround to avoid re-training (fitting) for bootstrapping?

Comment: If you want p-values for differences you could use the permutation test for differences between classifiers that I just added. That doesn't need any refitting. With deep CNNs, I would try to get confidence intervals from the Fisher information matrix (basically the Hessian and you usually get automatic derivatives with torch, tensorflow, ...)

Comment: @Ingo, In the first section "Bootstrap for 95% confidence interval", how to get the **estimate** confidence interval, which in your answer is: **Naive Bayes: 0.986, Random Forest: 0.983, Multilayer Perceptron: 0.974**? Thanks

Comment: @passinger, not quite sure what you mean. Those numbers are the point estimates  of the area under the ROC curve. The question just imported that from as `from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score`.

Comment: @Ingo, I get it. the estimate value is just the return value of sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score(). As I get different value in my local environment, I can't sure where these values come from.

Comment: @Ingo don't you mean "auc_differences.append(auc1 - auc2)"? also sorry i don't understand how do you interpret the np.mean(auc_differences >= observed_difference) value? what is the null hypotheseis

Comment: is there a paper regarding the permutation test you used above?

Comment: @Maths12, I'm sure there is a paper, but this is such a general approach, that it's difficult to give a specific one. I would probably refer to some textbook. I think introspectively, much of the logic here is driven by Wasserman's "All of Statistics" book.

Comment: Doesn't that model in the code for CI have to be initialized every time?

Answer (score 0):

One can use the code given below to compute the AUC and asymptotic normally distributed confidence interval for Neural Nets.

```
tf.contrib.metrics.auc_with_confidence_intervals(
labels,
predictions,
weights=None,
alpha=0.95,
logit_transformation=True,
metrics_collections=(),
updates_collections=(),
name=None)
```

Comment: I used this, it returns a tensor object. How am I supposed to check the results?

Comment: Tensorflow vs sklearn?